# Exit transition not triggered in Framer Motion for React components rendered in Array.map() (or conditionally)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-dom, framer-motion

I am trying to use the `framer-motion` package's `AnimatePresence` component to animate components as they enter/leave the DOM.

I have a section in my app that renders components in a table using `Array.map()`, where each item in the table has `initial`, `animate`, `exit`, and `transition` props. The array which gets mapped is stored in state using `React.useState`. Components correctly enter the DOM with a transition animation on page load, and they also exit the DOM with a transition on page navigation.

The effect I'm trying to create is for all items except the one clicked to transition off screen.

The issue I'm having is that when the array of items is updated using `React.useState` and `Array.filter()`, the items disappear without a transition. It doesn't seem to be an issue with `React.useState` updating with a new array, because when I add duplicate elements using `Array.concat()` (which returns a new array), they correctly transition on screen at the bottom of the table, while the existing components remain where they are and aren't re-mounted.

The components are no longer rendered, but it seems as though they are not actually being unmounted when the array updates. If so, why aren't they unmounted? Is there a way to render components with `Array.map()` and then manually unmount them conditionally from the parent on a state change?

*Note: In addition to `Array.map()` this also occurs when you conditionally render a component using `&&` or a ternary operator.*

Here's my code:

```
const data = [
  { title: "Item 1", Description: "First item", id: 1 },
  { title: "Item 2", Description: "Second item", id: 2 },
  { title: "Item 3", Description: "Third item", id: 3 },
  { title: "Item 4", Description: "Fourth item", id: 4 },
  { title: "Item 5", Description: "Fifth item", id: 5 }
];

export default function App() {
  const [arrayItems, setArrayItems] = React.useState(data);

  const handleClick = (item) => {
    // Correctly displays entrance animation for new element
    // setArrayItems(arrayItems.concat([item]));

    // Does not show exit animation for deleted elements
    setArrayItems(arrayItems.filter((element) => element.id === item.id));
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setArrayItems(data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AnimatePresence>
        <table style={{ borderCollapse: "collapse" }} key="1">
          {arrayItems.map((item) => (
            <ListItem handleClick={handleClick} item={item} key={item.id} />
          ))}
        </table>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
}
```

code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/white-field-6evzg?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the `framer-motion` documentation again, I was able to figure out what the issue was. The documentation says that:

*"The component being removed must be a direct descendant of* `AnimatePresence` *due to limitations with React."*

So the fix is just to change my code from this:

```
<AnimatePresence>
  <table style={{ borderCollapse: "collapse" }}>
    {arrayItems.map((item) => (
      <ListItem
       handleClick={handleClick}
       item={item}
       key={item.id}
      />
    ))}
  </table>
</AnimatePresence>
```

To this:

```
<table style={{ borderCollapse: "collapse" }}>
  <AnimatePresence>
    {arrayItems.map((item) => (
      <ListItem
       handleClick={handleClick}
       item={item}
       key={item.id}
      />
    ))}
  </AnimatePresence>
</table>
```

Strangely, in the case of my actual code, `AnimatePresence` is actually wrapping the root DOM element in `gatsby-browser.js`, but `motion` components several layers down would successfully animate using the exit animation (but only on page navigation). I'm still not quite sure why it works in the case of page navigation and not for conditionally rendered components, but it must have something to do with the way React unmounts components under the hood.

Framer docs: https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/##animating-custom-components

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this solution

Please do the following code change, this will provide remaining item after removing the target item.

```
setArrayItems(arrayItems.filter((element) => element.id === item.id));
```

Changed to

```
setArrayItems(arrayItems.filter((element) => element.id !== item.id));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not what I'm trying to do. The issue I am having is that when these items are removed from the array, they disappear, but do not animate. I need an animation to be triggered when the components leave the screen.